# Html layout with <DIV> work on html editor but not on brownser

Tags: html

And in my html editor looks just fine:
[alt text http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/7348/bien.png](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/7348/bien.png)

But when i see it on the browser (Chrome & Firefox) looks like this:
[alt text http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/642/malhh.png](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/642/malhh.png)

Im very new to layout with  tag, any idea of what im making worng?

Comment: You really should be putting your CSS in your <head> of your document, especially for the repeated elements (such as your two <input>s). It lessens the typing load and it makes it easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `"margin: auto;"` in the style of div **contenido** and **usuario**. Then add `padding-top: 58px;` in div **usuario** (as you are trying to put that div 58px lower.)

Oh! of course remove those `margin-top` styles from every where and use padding style instead.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong? You're relying on the rendering engine of your HTML editor and you shouldn't.

Only use a recent version of Firefox, Safari, Chrome or Opera for testing (edit: I forgot IE8 and I shouldn't have; it's support of CSS2.1 is good. It just lacks dozens of extensions but that's another story), then the other browsers including IE and forget your not-so-awesome rendering tool.

Answer (score -1):

I believe your specific issue is being caused by the lack of trailing semicolons at the end of your style properties. That will often cause bad rendering.

```
 margin-top: 1px" >
```

should be

```
 margin-top: 1px;" >
```

Also, you should definitely take the advice of @Christian Mann and put the CSS in the  of your document or, even better, in an external stylesheet. Inline CSS styles should be avoided.